# sys doesn't import properly when importing another module

Tags: python, nameerror, sys

I have been trying to import a custom module called 'nester' and this module uses sys.stdout. If I try to import nester I get an error. What is the issue here?

```
import sys 
import nester

x = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
nester.print_lol(x)
```

This is the nester module

```
def print_lol(the_list, indent=False, level=0, fh=sys.stdout):
    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_lol(each_item, indent, level+1, fh)
        else:
            if indent:
                for tab_stop in range(level):
                    print("\t", end='', file=fh)
            print(each_item, file=fh)
```

I was able to install the module locally without any errors but it still doesn't work. I've been trying to search for a solution for 2 hours with no luck so any help would be appreciated. I am following a tutorial by Head First Python from p. 126.

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled7/scratchpad", line 2, in <module>
    import nester
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nester.py", line 1, in <module>
    def print_lol(the_list, indent=False, level=0, fh=sys.stdout):
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: @sevenwheels **edit the question** with a [mcve].

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to import sys from within the nester module.  Just add `import sys` to the top of `nester.py`.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. The book makes no mention of adding this line of code in the module though. Was there a change in Python or something?

Comment: No, I think it's always been that way.  If you reference something from module A within module B, then module B has to import it from module A.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `sys` in the submodule itself, such that the full source code reads

```
import sys

def print_lol(the_list, indent=False, level=0, fh=sys.stdout):
    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_lol(each_item, indent, level+1, fh)
        else:
            if indent:
                for tab_stop in range(level):
                    print("\t", end='', file=fh)
            print(each_item, file=fh)
```

Note the added import on the first line.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the book and it makes no mention of adding this code. Would you know why it might have been omitted?